# On Teaching Cyclic Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

My professor asked me to take 20 mins on talking about Cyclic Groups and their practical applications in front of the whole class.

How should I start? Can anyone please help me.

Comment: A possibly good place to look is: Francis [Frank] James Budden, [**The Fascination of Groups**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521080169), Cambridge University Press, 1972, xviii + 596 pages. Your library might have a copy, and [it can be borrowed at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/fascinationofgro0000budd). Budden's book contains a very large number of wide-ranging (math and real-world) examples and it is very accessible/elementary -- doesn't require much mathematical background or mathematical maturity.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read your course literature to find out about applications of cyclic groups.
2. Think about example cyclic groups and where those might be used.
3. Think of practical examples where something goes in a cycle, and think how to model it as a cyclic group.